# How to find bounds on the Euler characteristic

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected planar graph. This graph has an [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) given by $\chi=v-e+f$, where $v$ is the number of vertices, $e$ the number of edges and $f$ the number of faces.

I know that $\chi$ is a non-negative integer, but I was wondering which values $\chi$ can assume. Is it possible to determine some bounds on $\chi$?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, $\chi$ isn't bounded, and it can be negative or positive. For example, $\chi$ for a [double torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_torus) is $-2$.

For planar graphs, $\chi$ is always 2. See [this page](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/) for several proofs of this fact.

$\chi$ for a compact surface is given by the formula:

$$\chi = 2(1 - g)$$

Where $g$ is the [genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29) of the surface, or more intuitively, the number of holes in it. This shows that $\chi$ can be decreased as much as we want by increasing the number of holes in a compact surface.

On the other hand, $\chi$ for $n$ disconnected spheres is $2n$. So similarly, we can increase $\chi$ as much as we want by increasing the number of spheres.

See Wikipedia's article for [many more examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Examples).

Comment: Of course we mustn't forget our non orientable friends- connected sum of projective planes which have $\chi$ = $2-n $, where n is the number of projective planes. :)

Answer (score 0):

"[The Euler characteristic of any planar connected graph $G$ is 2.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs)"